# Tailwindcss + nextjs import ALL utility classes

Tags: next.js, tailwind-css

Tailwind Framework: How can I include all classes in browser dev mode using NextJS and Tailwind?

Tailwind is a great framework, but I've run into a limitation that is making my development process harder. I'm using NextJS and Tailwind, and Tailwind builds the final CSS based on the usage of Tailwind classes in the source React code. The result is that if I don't use a class like "mt-4", it's not included in the final build. This is an optimization, but in dev mode, I would like to be able to have all classes available in the browser so I can play with the UI in the dev console without needing to edit my source code and rebuild. Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

Use a very broad [regular expression safelist](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#using-regular-expressions) like:

```js
module.exports = {
  // …
  safelist: [
    {
      pattern: /^/,
      variants: [
        'sm',
        'md',
        'lg',
        'xl',
        '2xl',
        // …
      ],
    },
  ],
  // …
}
```

Or consider using the [Tailwind CDN](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation/play-cdn).